# "Resolving Country Code Bug: How to Fix the country code?"

Tags: laravel-5

```
 <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="form-label required">{{ __('frontend.phone_number') }}</label>
                                <input  class="form-control mobilenumber @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror phone"
                                    type="tel" id="number" name="mobile" onkeypress='validate(event)'>

                                <input type="hidden" id="code" name="countrycode" value="1">

                                @error('mobile')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
```

Here i want my country code will be bangladesh and it will be fixed.